# Finding the root nodes of all the of a tree from a nodes in any generic list

Tags: c#, search, tree

This is a entity and i want to list all the children node for a given node in a generic function

```
    public static List<T> BuildTree<T>(List<T> list, T selectNode string keyPropName, string parentPropName, string levelPropName, int level = 0)
    {
        List<T> entity = new List<T>();

        foreach (T item in list)
        {


        }


        return entity;
    }
```

example of the entity structure

```
    protected long _coakey;
    protected long _parentkey;
    protected string _coacode;
    protected string _coacodeclient;
    protected string _coaname;
    protected int _coalevel;

    [DataMember]
    public long coakey
    {
        get { return _coakey; }
        set { _coakey = value; this.OnChnaged(); }
    }

    [DataMember]
    public long parentkey
    {
        get { return _parentkey; }
        set { _parentkey = value; this.OnChnaged(); }
    }

    [DataMember]
    public string coacode
    {
        get { return _coacode; }
        set { _coacode = value; this.OnChnaged(); }
    }

    [DataMember]
    public string coacodeclient
    {
        get { return _coacodeclient; }
        set { _coacodeclient = value; this.OnChnaged(); }
    }

    [DataMember]
    public string coaname
    {
        get { return _coaname; }
        set { _coaname = value; this.OnChnaged(); }
    }

    [DataMember]
    public int coalevel
    {
        get { return _coalevel; }
        set { _coalevel = value; this.OnChnaged(); }
    }
```

Comment: It's entirely unclear to me what you're trying to achieve...

Comment: You can't really return a tree as List<T>... Anyway, for dynamic property access, etc, see [Reflection](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/17269/Reflection-in-C-Tutorial).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved it my self hope it help you

```
    public static List<T> BuildTree<T>(List<T> list, T selectedNode, string keyPropName, string parentPropName, int endLevel = 0, int level = 0)
    {
        List<T> entity = new List<T>();
        Type type = typeof(T);
        PropertyInfo keyProp = type.GetProperty(keyPropName);
        string _selectedNodekey = keyProp.GetValue(selectedNode, null).ToString();

        PropertyInfo parentProp = type.GetProperty(parentPropName);
        foreach (T item in list)
        {

            string _key = keyProp.GetValue(item, null).ToString();
            string _parent = parentProp.GetValue(item, null).ToString();

            if (_selectedNodekey == _parent)
            {
                T obj = (T)Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(T));
                obj = item;
                entity.Add(obj);
                if (level == endLevel && level!=0) break;
                entity.AddRange(BuildTree<T>(list, obj, keyPropName, parentPropName, level + 1));
            }
        }


        return entity;

    }
```

Comment: You're calling `GetProperty(keyPropName)` twice which is useless. Also, move those calls to the outside of the loop, because it is a waste doing them over and over again. Secondly, representing a tree as a list is one of the ugliest things I've ever seen, no offense.

Comment: I need a list for my combo so i need to work with a list...and thanks for the suggtion

Comment: `selectedNodeKeyProp` and `keyProp` are still the exact same. Lose one of them.

Answer (score 0):

Your `BuildTree<T>` method cannot determine the structure of the tree unless it knows something about its structure.  At a very minimum, I would suggest making a base class or interface that defines a tree node, and then change the `BuildTree` method to work specifically with those types of objects.  Then, it will be able to figure out the tree structure.  Each of you entity classes would have to implement that tree node interface or inherit from the tree node base class.  For instance:

```
public abstract class TreeNodeBase
{
    public long parentkey
    {
        get { return _parentkey; }
        set { _parentkey = value; this.OnChanged(); }
    }
    protected long _parentkey;
}

public class MyEntityTreeNode : TreeNodeBase
{
    public long coakey
    {
        get { return _coakey; }
        set { _coakey = value; this.OnChanged(); }
    }
    protected long _coakey;

    // etc...
}

// Note the generic type constraint at the end of the next line
public static List<T> BuildTree<T>(List<T> list, T selectNode, string keyPropName, string parentPropName, string levelPropName, int level) where T : TreeNodeBase
{
    List<T> entity = new List<T>();
    foreach (TreeNodeBase node in list)
    {
        long parentKey = node.parentkey;
        // etc...
    }
    return entity;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Node class:**

```
public class Node<TKey, TValue> where TKey : IEquatable<TKey>
{
    public TKey Key { get; set; }
    public TKey ParentKey { get; set; }
    public TValue Data { get; set; }

    public readonly List<Node<TKey, TValue>> Children = new List<Node<TKey, TValue>>();
}
```

**TreeBuilder:**

```
public static Node<TKey, TValue> BuildTree<TKey, TValue>(IEnumerable<Node<TKey, TValue>> list,
                                                         Node<TKey, TValue> selectNode)
    where TKey : IEquatable<TKey>
{
    if (ReferenceEquals(selectNode, null))
    {
        return null;
    }

    var selectNodeKey = selectNode.Key;

    foreach (var childNode in list.Where(x => x.ParentKey.Equals(selectNodeKey)))
    {
        selectNode.Children.Add(BuildTree(list, childNode));
    }

    return selectNode;
}
```

**Usage:**

```
List<MyClass> list = ...

var nodes = list.Select(x => new Node<long, MyClass>
                                 {
                                     Key = x.MyKey,
                                     ParentKey = x.MyParentKey,
                                     Data = x
                                 }).ToList();

var startNode = nodes.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Data.Stuff == "Pick me!");

var tree = BuildTree(nodes, startNode);
```

**MyClass example:**

```
public class MyClass
{
    public long MyKey;
    public long MyParentKey;
    public string Name;
    public string Text;
    public string Stuff;
}
```